# programmatically change selected rows in a slickgrid

Tags: selection, slickgrid

Using slickgrid, I need to select/deselect rows on the fly, and here is my code, it seems to work but sounds a bit suboptimal really, is there any smater means to do this ?

```
// turn records checkbox on or off depending on 'checked'

function set_checkbox (record, checked) {  
   var id = record[primary_key];
   var index = dataview.getIdxById(id);
   var selectedRows=this.slick_grid.getSelectedRows();
   if (checked) // add index in current list
      selectedRows=selectedRows.concat(index);
   else // remove index from current list
      selectedRows=selectedRows.filter(function(idx) {return idx!=index;});
   this.slick_grid.setSelectedRows(selectedRows);
}
```

The grid is initialized with this selection model here:

```
grid.setSelectionModel (new Slick.RowSelectionModel ({selectActiveRow: false}));
```

Comment: Were you able to find better way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

This is quite simple using the grid helper method setSelectedRows(rowsArray)

The full description is here:

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Handling-selection

Comment: It should be noted that "setSelectedRows" does NOT set the "activeRow" property and thus does not set the active css class to the row. You have to call setActiveCell for that apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is correct if the rows are visible. However, programmatic selection typically means you have a different view of the same data and if the row containing selected item is hidden (due to filtering, group being collapsed, etc) then you really need to dig deeper and patch slickgrid to be able to select rows by Id. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean; as-is, this answer is incomplete and not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just need one change that is the **setSelectedRows** method takes parameter in the form of Array which are represented in the form of **[]**.
Change this line:

```js
   this.slick_grid.setSelectedRows([selectedRows]);
```

It might work.